# getting android source code onto eclipse in a way that it can compile

Tags: android, eclipse, mms, android-source

I am trying to write an app that uses the native android messaging app and adds modifications to it, can you give me, a windows 7 eclipse indigo user, an explanation of how to get the source to my machine and have it be able to compile?
I already tried: going to android.git.kernel.org and getting the snapshot of the mms app project; getting the android source code in .zip format and importing it as an external JAR to my referenced libraries (there was something wrong with that though...the package icons were transparent as opposed to the ones in the Google API's which were brown); importing the project using Git

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to write an app that uses the native android messaging app and adds modifications to it, can you give me, a windows 7 eclipse indigo user, an explanation of how to get the source to my machine and have it be able to compile?

The "native android messaging app" is not a standalone application, designed to be build with the Android SDK. It can only be built as part of building the entire firmware.

If your objective is to build replacement firmware for a device, visit http://source.android.com/source/index.html and follow the instructions in the "Getting Started" heading on the left, plus perhaps the "Using Eclipse" page.

If your objective is to build a standalone app, you will need to not only modify "the native android messaging app" with your "modifications", but also get rid of all its other internal dependencies. This may take weeks to months for you to accomplish.

Comment: What if I just want to add functionality to the existing app? is there a way to do that without building the firmware, also what if i tried to use the source as a JAR in eclipse shouldnt the app have all its internal dependancies from there, and how would i bring the source in as a JAR so it would work if I could do that?

Comment: @Shimon G: " is there a way to do that without building the firmware" -- no. "shouldnt the app have all its internal dependancies from there" -- no.